# How to handle "CHANNEL_MESSAGES_DISABLED" error on telegram?

Tags: c#, telegram

I want to send a text message to a private channel that I created. I am an administrator.

The code that I used for this goal is:

```
public async Task SendMessageToChannel(int ChannelId, long Access_hash, string message) 
{ 
    var request = new SendMessageRequest(new InputPeerChannelConstructor(ChannelId, Access_hash), message); 
    await _sender.Send(request); 
    await _sender.Recieve(request);
}
```

However, I receive the error **"CHANNEL_MESSAGES_DISABLED"**. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Will Ray, thanks for your edition.